# Missing SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, ssms

I installed SQL 2008 Enterprise edition all work properly during the installation all requirement are passed then after click finish go to :

start --> All Programs --> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 --> only found **the Configuration Tools and import export data**

any help plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During installation you need to make sure to install management tools.

Answer (score 0):

I get that occasionally when istalling on a rebuilt machine or server. I have no idea why it happens, but to make sure it doesnt happen, I normally choose the path where I choose the features during install and make sure you have the i think its called client tools or something checked for install. I used to get it all the time until I changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different versions installed, it will show only one of them in the Start/Program Files Menu. However you might be able to find the exe file down the road at somewhere like:

"$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

for the 2008 version and

"$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe"

for the 2005 version.