# How to copy sql server database from one to another server without any backups

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have two machines, A and B. In my machine A, I have SQL server with some database. I need to copy the database from Machine A to B without taking any backups. How do I do that?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Copy Database functionality in SQL Server Management Studio.

Right-click the database, select "Tasks", "Copy database". If you can take the database offline, you can also choose to detach it, copy the files to the new server, and then reattach the database after.

See also the Microsoft Documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

Comment: I have Sql Server Management Studio 2008. In this there is no option in copy database.

Comment: Odd, it should be there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Is it possible you are not a member of the sysadmin role? That's the permission level you need.

Comment: How can i add the member of the sysadmin role? Can you please say clearly

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, expand Security, then Login. Find the login you want to assign the permissions to. On the Server Roles page, then check the "Sysadmin" box. Granting these permissions might require you to be in a specific role already, though.

Comment: I have added the Sysadmin permission to my user. But Still i can't able to find the copy option by right clicking the database. What should i do now?

Comment: Are both the source and target system running SQL 2008? It sounds weird, as the Copy Database functionality should be in the client, and has been from SQL Server 2005. What edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Is it possible that you did not install the Management Tools during installation?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577966/missing-sql-management-studio

Comment: Ya I installed full SQL Server Management Studio. also i'm seeing the Management Studio Tool option in start->all programs-> SQL SERVER2008

Comment: Is it possible you are using SQL Server Express Edition? Apparently that does not have the Copy Database option. In that case, you probably would be best of making a backup. If, for whatever reason, that is not possible, you would have to use detach/attach. Keep in mind the latter option would make the database unavailable for access while the copy is taking place.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one more method that you can use only if you have direct access to both the machines.

In Source Machine:

1. Open Sql Server Management Studio(SSMS)

2. Right Click on Database you want to copy

3. Goto Properties

4. Select Files in Left Hand Menu

5. Scroll to Right Most columns you will find the filename and path of database file (note this path and filename of all the entries in the list)

6. Close the properties window

7. Again Right Click on Database

8. Click on Detach

9. Goto the path that you noted on Step 5

10. Copy all the files that you noted in step 5

11. Paste it in a folder in Target macine

12. Again Goto SSMS and Right Click on Database folder

13. Click on Attach

14. Click on Add and give the path of .mdf file you noted in Step 5

On Target Machine

1. Goto SSMS and Right Click on Database folder

2. Click on Attach

3. Click on Add and give the path of .mdf file you Copied from source Machine to Target machine.

**EDIT** 
You can create a linked server (refer:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) and use Cross server query to insert data into target database e.g

```
Select * Into Servername.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName From SourceSchemaName.Tablename
```

you don't need to perform this for each and every object, you can use cursors to do this for all the objects present in your database.

Comment: That method i know. While doing this method we need to store the files in the hard disk. My database is very big. per day i'm storing nearly 500 GB. so to avoid this what is the solution? Now you got my question.

Comment: Not Express Edition then :) Is it possible the Management Studio is from the Express Edition? Keep in mind that the Copy Database functionality would either detach/attach as well, or do an online copy, which with a database this size, would take large amounts of time as well.

If you are dealing with that scale of a database, you might be better off looking at alternatives to duplicate your data, such as snapshots (or SAN snapshots).

Comment: Please try the method i have mentioned in edit part, let me know if you encounter any problem.

Comment: Serious, you know how mongodb databases copy data to another server? 'Right click -> Copy database to other server'

Answer (score 3):

Just used a free tool from http://dbcopytool.codeplex.com/ to copy a live database from SQL 2005 to SQL 2012. After inputing all the info in the 2nd tab page, the 1st tab page can be configured and it all worked without issue.