# SQL Server 2014 Create a Copy of an Existing Database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

I've been trying to make a copy of a SQL Server Database (2014) and the recommended way to do this using SQL Server Management Studio seems to be the following.

```
Right Click Database >
    Tasks >
        Generate Scripts >
            Advanced (Schema and Data) (Single file per object)
```

Then I have to update the references to the database name to use the new database name.

This won't work for me though because some of the object files it outputs can be over a GB which means I can't open the file to change the database name.

Is there another way to create a copy of a database to a new database with a different name?

Comment: By far the easiest way in terms of fidelity is to make a backup and restore it under a different name. Any reason that's not an option?

Comment: I thought that's what I was trying to do above, If not what is the process?

Comment: [Backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187510) and [restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177429). Make sure to use a copy-only backup if this is a production database.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't realize there was an entirely different procedure for creating a backup that worked perfectly and was really fast. Thanks a bunch for your help

Answer (score 1):

I use this script for that.

```
declare @nameSuffix varchar(50) = 'DB_NEW_NAME'
declare @path varchar(250) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\YOUR PATH\MSSQL\'
declare @backupfile varchar(250) = @path + 'Backup\' + @nameSuffix + '.bak'
declare @moveFile varchar(300) = @path + 'DATA\' + @nameSuffix + '.mdf'
declare @moveLogFile varchar(300) = @path + 'DATA\' + @nameSuffix + '_log.ldf'

backup database DB1
to disk = @backupfile
with init, noformat, skip, stats=10

use master

restore database DB_NEW_NAME
from disk = @backupfile 
with replace,
 recovery,
move 'DB1' to @moveFile,
move 'DB1_Log' to @moveLogFile
```

Comment: Is this a TSQL script?

Comment: yes you can run it from SQL Server Management Studio. Just check the path first so you have the correct value in the @path variable

Comment: I really, really like this answer because I try to keep procedures in code as much as possible but I am unfamiliar with TSQL and I'm not sure what the two extra files are (mdf and ldf)

Comment: MDF is your database and LDF is the log file of your database. If your database is called DB1 than there will be a DB1.mdf and a DB1_log.ldf file

Comment: THis script makes a backup of DB1 and than restores it into DB_NEW_NAME and than changes the references that sql server has to DB1 to DB_NEW_NAME inside the copy database so that DB_NEW_NAME is complete independant of DB1

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the database by:

right click database to be copied > tasks > copy database

the database wizard will guide you to create your new copy.

more resources here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

Comment: Hello hermione, my installation does not have the option Copy Database

Comment: I see, would you give us the version/edition of the database and the management studio?

Comment: It's SQL Server Management Studio 2014 (Essentials)

Comment: perhaps if you try the answer here <http://stackoverflow.com/a/12407848/3078077> it night work for you